# How can I get my output to grab specific values from a column and then show entire row?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first attempt at coding and essentially I am writing a code that will go to a CSV file, look for symbols in a column and then include the entire row in the output.

Current issue I am having is that the output file contains all values whose string match the symbol i want to look up.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
n = "20210112"
path = r'//mydrive/repo/{}/Reports/DEP-leg{}.csv'.format(n, n)
df = pd.read_csv(path)
final = df[df['Risk Factor 1'].str.contains('AAPL|IPOF')] #enter symbol to look up here. Can enter multiple eg "JE|ATP|POT"
finall = filtered_frame = final.iloc[:, [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17]]
finall.to_csv(r"\\Analysis\{}/{}_Vol_Check.csv".format(n, n))
```

Risk Factor 1 is the column. What change do I need to make so that my output file only contains the symbols I want it to look up?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add regex = True in your search!

```py
import pandas as pd
n = "20210112"
path = r'//mydrive/repo/{}/Reports/DEP-leg{}.csv'.format(n, n)
df = pd.read_csv(path)
final = df[df['Risk Factor 1'].str.contains('AAPL|IPOF', regex=True)] #enter symbol to look up here. Can enter multiple eg "JE|ATP|POT"
final = final.iloc[:, [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17]]
final .to_csv(r"\\Analysis\{}/{}_Vol_Check.csv".format(n, n))
```

Comment: Heyy regex=true did not work. I believe it may be due to the way symbols are shown in the file.  The CSV file mentions the symbols like: EQTY_symbol_currency or EQTY_ss-symbol_currency.  If we assume  X is the symbol and CAD is the currency, is there a command that will go and only return rows for the following values: EQTY_X_CAD and EQTY_ss-X_CAD? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add your DataFrame with a couple of the actual rows? (just go with df.to_dict() and add the printed output so that I can work with that)

Comment: i wasnt able to get the expected output but ill try to simplify it: Column header is 'Risk Factor 1'   Will use AAPL as an example.  The values under the column are: 'EQTY_AAPL_USD' or 'EQTY_ss-AAPL_USD' or EQTY_AAPL_CAD or EQTY_ss-AAPL_CAD..  Id like to enter 'AAPL' in my code and then for it to find these values in the mentioned column and not include something like APL AAP etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general this should work fine. For me the following works:

```
# csv file
bla,check
1,AAPL
2,JE
3,POT
4,NOPE
5,AAPL
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df[df['check'].str.contains("AAPL|JE")].iloc[:, [1]])
# prints:
# check
# 0  AAPL
# 1    JE
# 4  AAPL
```